# split and join string (list index out of range)

Tags: python-3.x

```
all_images = list(Path(r'D:/face/train').glob('**/*.jpg'))
np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(str(file))).flatten() for file in all_images])
Path = r'D:\face\train'
print(all_images[0])
```

output:
D:\face\train\F0002\MID1\P00009_face3.jpg

```
train_images = ([x for x in str(all_images) if val_families not in x])
val_images = ([x for x in str(all_images) if val_families in x])

train_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

ppl = ([str(x).split("\\")[-3]  + "\\" + str(x).split("\\")[-2] for x in str(all_images)])
print(ppl[0])
```

output:  F0002\MID1

```
train_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

for x in train_images:
    train_person_to_images_map[str(x).split("\\")[-3] + "\\" + 
str(x).split("\\")[-2]].append(x)

    val_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

    for x in val_images:
        val_person_to_images_map[str(x).split("\\")[-3] + "\\" + 
str(x).split("\\")[-2]].append(x)
```

here i'm getting an index error.

```
   IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b625191b3a8e> in <module>
      2 
      3 for x in train_images:
----> 4     train_person_to_images_map[str(x).split("\\")[-3] + "\\" + str(x).split("\\")[-2]].append(x)
      5 
      6     val_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

i'm getting index error. Please help me with this.

Comment: You are splitting on slashes (/) but your paths have backslashes (\\). Have you tried `x.split('\\')`

Comment: yes. But still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: What error you are getting? I tried `x.split("\\")[-3]  + "\\" + x.split("\\")[-2]` and it does just fine

Comment: Ahh... I see now that you are calling `str` on the list of paths: `str(all_images)`. You should instead be calling `str` on each Path object in all_images.

Comment: Given the above, try `ppl = ([str(x).split("\\")[-3]  + "/" + str(x).split("\\")[-2] for x in all_images])`

Comment: Yeah it's working